# NSAttributedString crashes on IOS 6.1

Tags: ios, ios6, nsstring, nsattributedstring

I use the NSAttributedString for 2 things:

1.To fill a UITextView with a HTML format string

2.To resize that TextView depending on the length of the content

```
NSAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[MyHTMLString dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding] options:@{ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType } documentAttributes:nil error:nil];

myTextView.attributedText = attributedString;

UITextView *calculationView = [[UITextView alloc] init];
[calculationView setAttributedText:attributedString];
CGSize size = [calculationView sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(screenWidth,FLT_MAX)];

CGRect frame_summary = CGRectMake(0, y, size.width, size.height);
myTextView.frame = frame_summary;
```

And it works great on IOS 7.1 but on IOS 6.1 crashes at the first line(EXC_BAD_ACCES)

As far as I Know NSAttributedString works on IOS 6.

Any clue?

And finally any advice or any alternative to use on IOS 5?

Thanks in advance

Comment: bt? how can I do that?

Comment: when there is a crash in iOS 6.1 then type bt on ur console that will backtrace the crash so u will get the crash details why r u getting the crash..

Comment: What is `MyHTMLString`? Are you using ARC or manual memory management? Have you tried to debug on ios 6.1?

Comment: NSAttributedString don't have any instance method for iOS 6.1 and below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (id)initWithData:(NSData *)data options:(NSDictionary *)options documentAttributes:(NSDictionary **)dict error:(NSError **)error
```

is available only from iOS 7.0.
as well as the flags you use in options. (**NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute** and **NSHTMLTextDocumentType**).

You should use this instead:

```
- (id)initWithString:(NSString *)str attributes:(NSDictionary *)attrs;
```

you can create the `str` from NSData like this for example:

```
- (NSString *)initWithData:(NSData *)data encoding:(NSStringEncoding)encoding;
```

goodluck.

Comment: Thank you! but if I init the `attributtedString` with `initWithString:myHTMLString` and when I set it to a `UITextView`, it shows the text as plain text with all the HTML tags . How can that `UITextView` "understand" those HTML tags(on IOS 6)?

Comment: Basically what your asking for to parse html tags into a string (or attributeString). There are a few ways to implement this, my suggestions is that you use a 3rd party class that already does it for you (i think: TTTAtributedLabel can do the job, but im not sure, google it). But hey just a thought - if you dont want to edit you text in the textView, why not use a UIWebView instead of UITextView? it will render your string automatically :)